# check condition using try and catch block-java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

I understand the basic try-catch, where we put methods that could possibly throw exceptions in the try block. But when we need to check if something is wrong, and throw an exception, is it correct to use the code below? And the exception is caught, the program will continue to execute?

I can't tell why the `try` is needed here, but without it eclipse says 'syntax error'. Thanks for your help in advance!

```
public run (){
    if (something !=true) {
          try{
                throw new Exception();
              }catch (Exception e){

              }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is correct. You have to use **try** since that is where the exception-throwing code is entered and where exceptions are caught (just using a catch block won't serve any purpose)

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, exceptions are used to let the calling code handle errors in your method.

If you just want to handle the error in `run`, you don't need exceptions:

```
public void run() {
    if (something != true) {
        // handle it
    }
}
```

If you want the calling code to handle the error instead, this is where you need exceptions:

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    if (something != true) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

And where you call `run`, use a try/catch block:

```
try {
    run();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle it
}
```

It is also recommended that you don't throw an `Exception` instance, use a custom subclass instead.